# Supporting multiple languages in Solr

Tags: solr

I want to know how to return the response based on site language.
for example:

```
"name": {
       "en": "Berlin",
       "nl": "Berlijn",
}
```

The site language is "nl", so the name fields value should be return as "Berlijn"
Is that possible to implement in solr?

I read about collection translation, but I want the user to search in both language but the response value will show based on site language, also I read about detect language but I don't think this is the solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Pick which field to display based on what the current language selection is? i.e. instead of trying to do this in Solr (which you can do with field aliasing), it's probably easier to do by just displaying the field that matches the correct suffix instead.

Comment: @MatsLindh currently in the application I display the field e.g[nl] based on the site language. but I want to return only one value during the query from the API and store it in the "name" field.

Comment: In that case [you can use field aliasing](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/common-query-parameters.html#CommonQueryParameters-FieldNameAliases) - `fl=name:<name of field you want to select>` - since you have a hierarchy I'm not sure what the mapping field name would be, possibly `name.en`?